# Google AppEngine use Google Compute for Task?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I need to run some specific code that can't be run on Google AppEngine (because of restrictions).

Since these workers are asynchronous, I thought about launching a Compute instance every time I need it and connecting them via a specific Tasks via the Task Queue from Google AppEngine, but I can not find any documentation about if this is possible?

TL;DR: Is it possible to specify a Google Compute as instance for a Task queue?

Comment: Aside: there's no need to add thanks and other chatty material to your posts - we prefer succinct here. [This is relevant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to specify a Google Compute as instance for a Task queue.

But did you consider using the Flexible environment (eventually with a [custom runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/about-custom-runtimes) to try to address the restrictions) instead? Or the alternatives suggested for the Flexible env (only has limited task queue support) From [Task Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-app-engine):

> The Task Queue service has limited availability outside of the
>   standard environment. If you want to use the service outside of the
>   standard environment, you can sign up for the [Cloud Tasks alpha](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1g6yRocQ3wtdTArfO4JX8DoqOhYmsoTVgrlFnS0mV1bo/viewform?edit_requested=true).
>
> Outside of the standard environment, you can't add tasks to [push
>   queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/#push_queues), but a service running in the flexible environment can be
>   the target of a push task. You can specify this using the
>   [`target`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/creating-tasks#specifying_the_worker_service) parameter when adding a task to queue or by specifying
>   the default `target` for the queue in [`queue.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/queueref).
>
> In many cases where you might use pull queues, such as queuing up
>   tasks or messages that will be pulled and processed by separate
>   workers, [Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/) can be a good alternative as it offers
>   similar functionality and delivery guarantees.

Comment: Thank you for your help! If I go with Pub/Sub, do you know if I have to manage the instance from Cloud Compute "manually" (via API) or is it managed automatically by Google? I like this about AppEngine, they spawn instances based on the workload, reducing the pricing.

Comment: If you use GAE Flex yes, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#services. But not with plain GCE.

Comment: Yes, but that's the issue, it works with AppEngine, which is limited (I need to install exotic stuffs on the server, C libraries, that can't be installed on GAE, that's why I'm looking to the awesome stuff from GAE (auto scaling, queue) while using GCE)

Comment: Well, GAE flex drops a lot of the restrictions from GAE standard, you can even use [Custom Runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build). Pretty much anything you can put in a dockerfile...

Comment: Ok, I think I need to .. rethink my project if I plan to use Google's service.